# send value to database then show result as alert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, join, alert

I don't know to say this. I have some input form which connected to two tables in database. First of all, i have two textfields :

```
<input type="text" id="model"> i type alfa
<input type="text" id="serial_number"> i type A0020
```

Table A :

```
Model      serial        start_serial        end_serial
alfa       301           A0001                A0100
alfa       101           A0101                A0200
```

Table B:

```
Model     serial       remark
alfa      301          delay
```

from information above i have two variables $model and $serial_number.
what I want to do is:

```
1. send variable to query, check the model and serial
2. in query i type SELECT.....WHERE A.Model = '$Model' //SEARCH all data which have value alfa
3. in this step i want to check $serial_number //if A0020 is in range start serial A0001 and end serial A0100
4. if match i will get result serial = 301
5. join table A to table B, LEFT JOIN ....ON A.Model=B.Model AND A.Serial=B.serial
6. so if i type alfa and A0020 in textfield i will get REMARK VALUE = delay
```

how to get last result as delay in my query? so i can show it as alert.

Comment: `data:"check="+data2+"&action=acceso"+"&serial="+data1;`

Comment: @4ndrew:how to show result as alert which alert value is delay?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this link. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ 
Also you can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"process.php",
    data:"&check="+data2+"&action=acceso",  //this works for my jquery projects
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    success: function(res){
                           alert(res);                              
                             }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really understand your question, so I'm basing my answer on the comment you left, summarizing the question

> "how to show result as alert which alert value is delay"

If you mean you want to show an alert where the value (text) of the alert is "delay":

`alert('delay');`

If you meant you want to show an alert after a delay, where the ajax response specifies the delay:

```
success: function(res){
         setTimeout(function() { alert(res); }, (int)res);                              
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading your updated question.

Your server side script will do all the communication with the database. Lets say its a PHP script

```
//make sure you sanitize input
$model = $_POST['model'];
$serial = $_POST['serial_number']

//this is a very poor query. I'm bad at SQL. Utilize Joins to make it better
// this is just to give you an idea
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `remark` FROM `yourtableB` WHERE `serial` IN 
(SELECT `serial` FROM `yourtableA` WHERE `Model` = '$Model' AND ('$serial' > `start_serial`) AND ('$serial' < `end_serial))");

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    $resp = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    echo $resp['remark'];
}
else
{
    echo "none";
}
```

Jquery side, modify the `success` function

```
success: function(res){
        if (res != "none")
        {
            alert(res);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('No data found');
        }
}
```

Comment: see my updated post. for additional information, delay is data inside remark column in database. I will get it if my inputed data is match (use query). But i'm still confuse how to get it.

Comment: that's give me a light for my confusing.don't worry about query i'm just need the method.very hard to say what exactly i need. i will try this first.